# How do you make snippets show in VB.NET for Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, intellisense, code-snippets

Okay so I am a C# developer at heart but have been working for a living in VB for a while now.  I never really thought about it till today but I used to love Snippets in Visual Studio and now I never use them or only sparingly for things like WPF properties.  I notice though they don't show up for me.  They work but don't give me the hints.  Is that by design or an option I can set to see them?

EG in simple console app I can type 'arrSort' and then hit enter and I get:

```
Dim animals() As String = {"lion", "turtle", "ostrich"}
Array.Sort(animals)
```

Cool what I want, no problem.  But I did not see any Intellisense for it and in C Sharp it shows up near immediately.  I know you can go (CTRL + K, X) to get a menu of snippets, but then going to another menu to another menu is kind of tedious and defeats the whole point of a time saving of just going '123' (Tab or Enter) and getting an auto fill in suggestion of what I am about to do in a little hover menu.

From my little experience in VB it seems that some of its Intellisense really shines for the core language features but in Intellisense for Snippets it is very lacking.  Is there an option I can just turn on?  Or am I relegated to having to memorize them or else have the go the traverse the menu option?  Because I may work in an area of File Access for a while and then have quick snippets for things with Stream Readers and Stream Writers, then come back in a few months and forget them but an auto fill in may help.

Comment: Is typing `arr?<tab>` sufficient? The `?` disappears and a menu of snippets whose shortcuts start with "arr" is presented.

Comment: @Andrew Morton Okay it was an IDE trick, if I type arr? when I go to type '?' it auto fills in with the existing intellisense.  But If Go 'arr' escape(to exit given suggestions), '?', then tab it will.  Else if you go further down the chain where something doesn't exist it will work.  If you do something that does though, as soon as you attempt to hit '?' it will auto give what it thinks you want.  Kind of weird on the IDE's part.  But this may be an acceptable answer as it is time saving and essentially what I wanted with a little bit of help.  You can provide an answer and this may be best.

Comment: You might as well write the answer - you seem to have it down to a fine art now :)

Comment: Interestingly enough, the `?<snippet>` method works kind of in C# (for me, at least), but the `?` doesn't go away, so you're left with an error. The `<snippet>?` doesn't work in C# for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Using VB:**

Type a partial snippet followed with a question mark, then press TAB to see list of possible snippets and their Intellisense.

`arr?` then <kbd>Tab</kbd>

Similarly, type the full snippet followed with a question mark, then press TAB to see the Intellisense for that snippet.

`arrSort?` then <kbd>Tab</kbd>

See [How to: Insert IntelliSense Code Snippets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165399(v=vs.100).aspx)